# How does this code print the last word the user inputs?

Tags: c, string, info

**This small piece of code takes a user input and returns the last word from the user input.**

*I don't exactly understand how those 2 lines of code work*

can someone explain why or how `printf( &last_word[i]);` when I is at position 0 prints the last word of the sentence entered by the user input.

the purpouse of the program is to print the last word of the user input, but I dont understand those lines of code, If I change something on those 2 lines, the code stops working and it doesnt return the last word entered by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){    
int i = 0;
char *last_word;
char str[800];
printf("enter:");
fgets(str,100,stdin);

while (str[i] != '\0')    {    
    if (str[i] == ' ' && str[i + 1] > 32) 
        last_word = &str[i + 1]; 
    i++;                         
}

 /*------------------------these next lines of code-----------------------*/
 /*----->    i = 0; 
 /*----->    printf( &last_word[i]);


       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to always use a string literal as the first argument of `printf`.

Comment: oh that's right, Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Code fails if  `str[]` lacks a `[ ]`.

Comment: @chux What does that mean?

Comment: @JL2210 Oops, typp: Code fails if `str[]` lacks a `' '` as .`last_word` is later used, but never set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy undefined behavior batman.

The while loop stuffs the address of the next character past a space character into `last_word`; thus if there are any space characters it points one past the last one.

`i = 0` therefore `&last_word[i]` is the same as `last_word`. So it uses the last word as a `printf` format string.

But that's not the same as last word. Try this input:  " %n%n%n%n%n%n%n%n". Goodbye.

The first argument to `printf` should almost always be a constant. You want `printf("%s",  last_word);` In fact, let us put it this way; the only reason to ever not pass a constant format string to `printf` and friends is your standard library is too old to support `%*d` for dynamic widths.